# Angular $http.post to Node api - 503 (hosting on Heroku)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I have a MEAN stack app that's mostly Angular, and I have an API on the node side that has an endpoint for me to verify a JSON Web Token. For some reason though, I check the dev console under network and see the api being accessed, but after taking forever (I think it times out) I get a 503 from the server.

**Angular**:

```
var verifyToken = function() {
        return $http.get('/oauth/verify', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getToken()
            }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers) {
            console.log('VERIFY STATUS' + status);
            console.log('VERIFY HEADERS' + headers("Authorization"));
        });
};
```

**API Routes**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var auth = jwt({
    secret: 'gas', // process.env.JWT_SECRET
    userProperty: 'payload'
});

var ctrlOauth = require('../controllers/oauth');
var ctrlCallback = require('../controllers/callback');
var ctrlVerify = require('../controllers/verifyJWT');

// authentication
router.get('/oauth', ctrlOauth.login);
router.get('/callback', ctrlCallback.callback);

// verify JWT
router.get('/verify', auth, ctrlVerify.verify);

module.exports = router;
```

**verifyJWT.js**:

```
module.exports.verify = function(req, res) {
    return true;
};
```

The idea is using `express-jwt` middleware to authenticate the route. The problem is that when I make the angular `get` request, it times out. Once again, this is hosted on Heroku. Any ideas? Thanks!

*Response Headers*:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:484
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 26 Oct 2016 21:57:27 GMT
Server:Cowboy
```

*Response*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style type="text/css">
        html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
        iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
      </style>
    <title>Application Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <iframe src="//s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">
        <p>Application Error</p>
      </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: what did you discover for this error?

Comment: I never figured it out. I might have been the Heroku application not updating to a specific version of a package. It could be a programmatic error. Not really sure.